# CSS Bootstrap table responsive lateral margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I insert margins on both sides of a table-responsive `<div>` such that I get the responsive behaviour on smaller screens but I see a small margin also on the right side of the table (fig right)?

If I just write `margin:0 1em`, for example, I can see the margin on the left of the screen, but the table gets to the end of the right border of the screen (fig left)...

[image]

Comment: Try to use margin: auto and then margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto with particular width and your div will be in center with responsive :) but use width in %..hope it will help..

Comment: Thanks. Fixing `width: 95%` and `margin:0 auto` solved it! ;)

Comment: i am happy that i was able to help..enjoy coding :)

Comment: @Sfrow if you fixed your code, make sure to answer and accept your own answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve, I just used:

```
 width: 95%;
 margin:0 auto;
```